# Biztalk sending email smtp using a orchestration

Tags: biztalk

I tried to follow the tutorial to send an SMTPemail form an orchestration, I attaches the link:

[Sending SMTP email from within BizTalk Orchestration](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/9dd0f346-baf9-4674-a50f-1716445b26bc/sending-smtp-email-from-w.aspx) (eggheadcafe.com)

and few thing was not clear:

1. must you add a host and hot instance to send an SMTPemail?
2. I follow the link and I added multi-part message (the message going to be send to the mail) and the construct message did not recognize it?

Comment: Can you try and explain a little bit more your questions? I don't understand what you're referring to in #1, and as for #2 - can you explain what you mean by "did not recognize it?" what was the error message you're seeing?

Comment: Also see SO question ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187750/send-html-email-in-biztalk-with-multiple-pdf-attachments-with-smtp-adapter

Answer (score 0):

For #1 I can assure you that you do not need to create a new host and host instance to get the tutorial running.

You may however want to create multiple hosts and host instances if you plan to create multiple smtp send adapters with different smtp host configurations (in a real life / production environment).