# Add PDF attachment to BizTalk email service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have come into ownership of a ASP.NET MVC site that utilizes Biztalk 2013 to handle tasks like sending emails. I am completely new to biztalk so forgive obvious mistakes in this post.

**Quick overview**

The service is called through the application and then the orchestration calls a stored procedure in a sql db to populate some of values for the email (including html for the email) and then sends the email out.

**I now want to add a pdf attachment to the email.**

As a test, I added a pdf file to the server and then I have tried adding `ActualEmailMsg(SMTP.Attachments) = "C:\\PDFs\\test.pdf";
ActualEmailMsg(SMTP.MessagePartsAttachments) = 2;` to the message assignment expression shape as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187750/send-html-email-in-biztalk-with-multiple-pdf-attachments-with-smtp-adapter) to no avail. (*I also tried the physical path with only 1 "\" like "C:\\PDFs\test.pdf" and that didn't work*)

I have ruled out the possibility of a lack of permissions from the service account to the PDF folder. The email sends correctly but no attachment is present. I am getting no errors in the code or in the event viewer on the server so at this point I am at a loss for what it might be.

Comment: Can you show me your send pipeline?

Comment: I believe the send pipeline was a custom made one. I don't think it was a default pipeline. It was called 'SendHTMLEmail'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of googling I found **the issue was related to the send pipeline**. [This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.biztalk.orchestration/GOJ8e4_Rd5k) got me on the right track.

In the send ports section of the BizTalk Admin Console of the app, the send pipeline was using a custom pipeline I believe was made by the previous owner. **I changed it to the 'Pass Thru Transmit'** type in the dropdown and it is now working.

Comment: Your "SendHTMLEmail" pipeline was using a multipart message with mime type encoder, that's why you were not getting your PDF File and that's why i asked you to show it to me :)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following pattern for sending Emails. I’m not sure but maybe you need to use the `ActualEmailMsg(MIME.FileName)` attribute for message in email.

```
ActualEmailMsg(MIME.FileName) ="Report_{"+FullFileName+"}.xml";
ActualEmailMsg(SMTP.CC)=ReportNotificationEmailAddress;
ActualEmailMsg(SMTP.Subject)="Report Notification Email";
ActualEmailMsg(SMTP.EmailBodyFile)=@"C:\...\ReportNotificationBody.htm";
ActualEmailMsg(SMTP.Attachments)=@"C:\..\ReportNotificationBody.png”;
ActualEmailMsg (SMTP.EmailBodyTextCharset)="UTF-8";
```

Comment: To make your answer better, you should explain what the `MIME.FileName`-attribure does and why you think it might solve the problem.